# Time inconsistency

Tags: java, date

I am trying to implement a time scheduling. When the transmission more than once ( in the code it is defined by **times** variable) the program must calculate the next transmission time of the selected test case by using interval of the test cases ( by this example 15 minutes). It means that this test case must test every devices in every 15 minutes. For next begin date is calculated by using needed test time ( in this example 1 second). firstTransmissionBeginDate is test begin date taken by the user by GUI.

Scenario: We have 1 job which has 15 minutes interval and 1 seconds needed time. It only tests the A group devices ( 2 device only) and our test duration is 1 hour. So we expected to see 4 times transmission. transmission 1.1 begins 18:30:00 and transmission 1.2 must begin 18:30:01. Transmission 2.1 must begin 15 minutes later 18:45:00 transmission 2.2 must begin 18:45:01. Transmission 3.1 must begin 15 minutes later 19:00:00 transmission 3.2 must begin 19:00:01 and so on.

However following code gives
  transmission 1.1 begins 18:30:00 and transmission 1.2 begins 18:30:01. Transmission 2.1 begins 15 minutes later 18:45:01 transmission 2.2  begins 18:45:01. Transmission 3.1  begins 15 minutes later 19:00:01 transmission 3.2 begins 19:00:01 and so on.

My code:

// Calculate next begin date

```
      Date tmpDate = df.parse(firstTransmissionBeginDate);
      long neededTestTime = (long) Math.ceil(selectJob.getNeededTestTime());
      Date nextBeginDate = new Date(tmpDate.getTime() + (neededTestTime * 1000));
      firstTransmissionBeginDate = df.format(nextBeginDate);
```

// For 2nd and more transmissions

```
  int times = 0;
  long intervalMiliseconds = selectJob.getInterval() * 1000;
  if (intervalMiliseconds <= differ) {
    times = (int) (differ / intervalMiliseconds);
  } else {
    times = (int) ((differ / intervalMiliseconds) + 1);
  }

  long neededTestTime = (long) Math.ceil(selectJob.getNeededTestTime());
  Date timesDate = df.parse(firstTransmissionBeginDate);
  timesDate = new Date(timesDate.getTime() - (neededTestTime * 1000));
  for (int i = 1; i < times; i++) {
    Date nextExecutionBeginDate = new Date(timesDate.getTime() + intervalMiliseconds);
    timesDate = nextExecutionBeginDate;
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is very unclear.  Please clarify with more examples and do not use screenshots. Provide the actual and expected results in text form.

Comment: @JimGarrison Done! Hopefully, this time my question seems more clear and understandable.

Comment: @limonik So you want to schedule an event to happen every *x* minutes for *n* occurrences?

Comment: @limonik In your scenario you say the test duration is one hour. But you only list pairs of runs for 18:30 and 18:45. That is half an hour not one hour.

Comment: @BasilBourque yes but I pointed out "so on". I did not want to repeat myself time period is between 18:30-19:30. You are right.

Comment: @limonik Please edit your Question to be precise. Giving a faulty example is counter-productive.

Comment: So you want to implement a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Comment: @Makoto at least I want to correct my code.  I have a huge project I do not want to make radical changes in my code.

Comment: Well... I think that's what you actually need.  You need some kind of cron job to do this since writing it yourself is tricky enough with `java.util.Date`, and further, it's essentially a solved problem.  Is your project using any framework like Spring, or does it have a cron library already in it?

Comment: Can you use Java 8? Have you considered using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor? Cron4j?

Comment: @assylias yes I am using Java8. But for every different job interval changes like 10 minutes every month, every year. How can I use Cron?

Comment: Unclear is time manipulation in the first snippet. If `firstTransmissionBeginDate` initially is moment of start of transmission A (1.1), which is 18:30:00, and next transmission A (2.1) must be performed exactly at 18:45:00 why do you need to add extra second to `nextBeginDate`, then substract it in second snippet? Won't be enough just to take initial `firstTransmissionBeginDate` as a starting point, and add interval to it--to get exact time of job A (2.1) next attempt?

Comment: For other jobs (2.2, 3.2 etc) you just take moment where first job A (2.1) should be started and subsequently add `neededTestTime`.

Comment: @limonik Are you trying to collect a list of start times? Or are you trying to execute Java at each of these times?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou nextBeginDate is needed for A1.2.

Comment: your code is buggy and ill-designed: you add the same quantity you subtract the same quantity  ... - take my code and place Dates instead of numbers: do you want 1 to be one minute? do that; do you want to be 1 second ? do that - do you want it to be one day?

Comment: @gpasch no need, I solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

The following program produces the numbers in the order you want - that is starting from zero 0, 1, 15, 16, 30, 31, etc.

```
      long firstTransmissionBeginDate=0;
      long tmpDate = firstTransmissionBeginDate;
      long neededTestTime = 15;
    System.out.println(firstTransmissionBeginDate);

// For 2nd and more transmissions

  int times = 0;
  long intervalMiliseconds = 15;

  long timesDate = firstTransmissionBeginDate;
  for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    long nextExecutionBeginDate = ((i%2)==1)?timesDate + 1:timesDate + intervalMiliseconds;
    System.out.println(nextExecutionBeginDate);
    if((i%2)==0) timesDate = nextExecutionBeginDate;
  }
```

You can wrap them in Dates and fire the events.

Comment: @gspasch after make a testing I observed that still it is not working

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should use a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and its method [scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). From the documentation:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period;
>   that is executions will commence after initialDelay then
>   initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on. If any
>   execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions
>   are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via
>   cancellation or termination of the executor. If any execution of this
>   task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may
>   start late, but will not concurrently execute.

So submit a runnable that sends whatever transmission you need when called, and set a period of 15 minutes. Something like:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: I know this plugin however my program not only adds the interval time but also the processing time. Sorry it is not a solution of my problem. Thank you for help.

Comment: @limonik Can you check the documentation then for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's scheduleWithFixedDelay instead of scheduleAtFixedRate? They operate almost the same, but scheduleAtFixedRate will schedule "with the given delay between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next"

Comment: +1 this answer directly addresses the question, but misses just a little of what OP is -poorly- expressing. I believe that the OP really does want scheduleAtFixedRate behavior, but wants it to FINISH executing at the exact quarter (18:30, 18:45), not to start at the exact quarter. Start the executor at 18:30 minus execution time and then you should get the behavior OP seems to be actually asking for. This assumes that execution time is a constant.